# Python geocoder REQUEST DENIED even with API key?

Tags: python, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I signed up for a google API key to geocode addresses.  I'm attempting to use Python's geocoder.

```
g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA', key='puting my key here')
```

However, it's still giving me:

```
<[REQUEST_DENIED] Google - Geocode [empty]>
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, I thought that Geocoding API might not be enabled at API console for the project retrieved the API key. Please confirm this. When the script is run after Geocoding API was enabled, the following response is returned.

```
<[OK] Google - Geocode [###]>
```

#### Note:

- If you know the project ID, you can open the page for enabling the API at

  - `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/geocoding-backend.googleapis.com?project=project-id-#####`
- About pricing, please check https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/.

#### References:

- [Google Maps Platform](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/)

If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

You can get more information about the error by attempting to load your request in a browser. You can get the URL with `g.url` in the below example:

```
>>> import geocoder
>>> g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA', key='puting my key here')
>>> g.ok
False
>>> g
<[REQUEST_DENIED] Google - Geocode [empty]>
>>> g.url
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mountain+View%2C+CA&bounds=&components=&region=&language=&key=puting%20my%20key%20here'
```

When I copied that result into a browser window it was clear:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

In my case, @Tanaike was right: even though I recall enabling the new API key, I had not enabled 'billing' on my Google Cloud Project (https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable).

Answer (score 1):

the geodecode API requires to pay. Put your billing info then you can use it.

Comment: please transform this answer to a comment as it is not offering a full solution, just a direction.

Comment: When you create a project, you have a section called billing. There you can do the link or either create if you have already no billing information associated.

Answer (score -1):

The previous responses were right. You needed to enable the billing in order to make requests. You can go to this website and enable billing. I think that's the only way you would be able to make requests.
https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable